# Access jQuery Datepicker array elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Been having a poke around and I am trying to be able to get the individual sections of the date chosen by the date picker as vars, so they can be used outside the .datepicker function.

Is there an array I can access to grab this data?

You can format the date as one of the functions options using `dateFormat: "dd mm yy"`  etc, so there must be a way just to set `dd` as `var day` `mm` as `var month` etc.

Comment: All those are private to the datepicker and to my knowledge there is no way to get them out (unless to modify their source), Out of curiosity why do you need it?

Comment: @Teja Kantamneni I want to be able to have a select field which a user selects the duration of an event. This duration will just add onto the date selected in the datepicker to give a finish date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know about the [getDate](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-getDate) and [setDate](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-setDate) methods of the datepicker ?

quoting the setDate

> The new date may be a Date object or a
>   string in the current date format 
>   (e.g. '01/26/2009'), **a number of days
>   from today (e.g. +7)** or **a string of
>   values and periods ('y' for years, 'm'
>   for months, 'w' for weeks, 'd' for
>   days, e.g. '+1m +7d')**, or null to
>   clear the selected date.

Answer (score 1):

We have two steps here:

1. Fetch selected date: the [getDate](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-getDate) method "*Returns the current date for the datepicker or null if no date has been selected*"
2. Format the date as string: the [formatDate](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate) utility function "*Format a date into a string value with a specified format*"

Follow the links for some usage examples.